# ros2 topic persisting more than one message

Tags: python, ros2

I have a very difficult problem with a ros2 topic that for some reason keeps more than one message. My project is rather simple: I have a planner in which I can create targets and edit them. The planner consists of several nodes, one for changing each value of the target. List of my nodes:

```
/add_target  
/change_comment  
/change_target_index  
/clear_state  
/remove_target  
/rename_target  
/set_target  
/toggle_select_target  
/toggle_visible
```

Each node extends StateNode (see implementation below), which helps to keep the same state for each node.

The idea is simple: a node receives a service call, for example /planner/rename_target, finds the specific target from the node's state, modifies it, and publishes new state to /planner/state. Each node is subscribed to /planner/state and sets the state to the message received. The idea is to keep the state consistent across all nodes, so each node has access to all state data and can modify it.

I have set my quality of service profile to keep ONLY the latest message. However, my problem is that **after using service calls to different nodes**, sometimes when running for example

```
ros2 topic echo --qos-history keep_last --qos-depth 1 --qos-durability transient_local --qos-reliability reliable /planner/state
```

I receive **multiple** messages. The order of the messages changes randomly. The state of each node seems to be the same, BUT it seems there are **old** messages "floating around" in the topic. My qos should allow only the latest message to persist.

For example, if I first service call twice

```
ros2 service call /planner/add_target mtms_interfaces/srv/AddTarget "{target: {position:{x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}, orientation: {alpha: 0.0,beta: 0.0,gamma: 0.0}}}"
```

my topic echo looks normal, but if I then

```
ros2 service call /planner/rename_target mtms_interfaces/srv/RenameTarget "{name: 'Target-0', new_name: 'example'}"
```

suddenly my topic echo shows two messages. In one of the messages the target has not been modified, and in the other the target has been modified.

**What could be the problem here?**

Here are some examples of my nodes

StateNode implementation:

```
class StateNode(Node):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

        # Persist the latest sample.
        qos = QoSProfile(
            depth=1,
            durability=DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL,
            history=HistoryPolicy.KEEP_LAST,
            reliability=ReliabilityPolicy.RELIABLE
        )

        self._state_publisher = self.create_publisher(
            PlannerState,
            "/planner/state",
            qos
        )
        self._state_subscriber = self.create_subscription(
            PlannerState,
            '/planner/state',
            self.state_updated,
            10
        )
        self._state = None

    def state_updated(self, msg):
        self._state = msg
```

RenameTargetNode implementation:

```
class RenameTargetNode(StateNode):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('rename_target')
        self.create_service(RenameTarget, '/planner/rename_target', self.rename_target_callback)

    def rename_target_callback(self, request, response):

        state = self._state
        if state is None:
            response.success = False
            return response

        self.get_logger().info('Renaming {} to {}'.format(request.name, request.new_name))
        
        i = 0
        for target in state.targets:

            # Name already exists
            if target.name == request.new_name: 
                response.success = False
                return response
            
            # Save index of target in case new_name is unique
            if target.name == request.name:
                i = state.targets.index(target) 
        
        state.targets[i].name = request.new_name

        self._state_publisher.publish(state)

        response.success = True
        return response
```

AddTargetNode implementation

```
class AddTargetNode(StateNode):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('add_target')
        self.create_service(AddTarget, '/planner/add_target', self.add_target_callback)

    def first_available_target_name(self):
        if self._state is None:
            return "Target-0"

        target_names = [target.name for target in self._state.targets]
        idx = 0
        while True:
            target_name = "Target-{}".format(idx)
            if target_name not in target_names:
                break
            idx += 1
        return target_name

    def create_new_target(self, pose):
        target = Target()

        target.name = self.first_available_target_name()
        target.type = "Target"
        target.comment = ""
        target.selected = False
        target.target = False  # XXX: Misnomer
        target.pose = pose

        target.intensity = 100.0
        target.iti = 100.0

        return target

    def add_target_callback(self, request, response):
        self.get_logger().info('Incoming request')

        target = self.create_new_target(
            pose=request.target  # XXX: Misnomer
        )

        if self._state is None:
            msg = PlannerState()
            msg.targets = [
                target
            ]
        else:
            msg = self._state
            msg.targets.append(target)

        self._state_publisher.publish(msg)

        response.success = True
        return response
```

System information:
Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.14.0-1042-oem, x86_64

I'm running the ros nodes in one docker container created with osrf/ros:galactic-desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I had several publishers to the same topic with DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL, which is described as follows: "the ***publisher*** becomes responsible for persisting samples for “late-joining” subscriptions." In practice this means that when a new subscriber joins, each publisher will send them their last message --> subscriber receives multiple messages.

There are several solutions for this, for example creating a master node that is subscribed to an inner state that is updated by each node, but only the master node is responsible for publishing the state "outside".